# How to traverse to the parent element and remove Style attribute

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a Button control in my Web form.  Here I put CSS styles through JQuery.  At some instance, I want to remove styles applied on page load.  I have to traverse to its parent span and DIV elements and remove them.  I would like to know that how could this be achieved.  After applying styles on page load the HTML markup looks like following:

```
<DIV class=jquery-roundedBtn>
<SPAN class=spanLt></SPAN>
<INPUT id=DefaultContent_btnRunReport class=edit-submit value="Run Report" type=submit   name=ctl00$DefaultContent$btnRunReport>
<SPAN class=spanRt></SPAN>
</DIV>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$('.spanLt, .spanRt, .jquery-roundedBtn').removeClass("name of class");
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you applying styles?  Hopfully you are just assigning a class to the element you want to style.  If this is the case you could remove it like so:

```
$(".mySelector").parent().removeClass("myClass");
```

I don't see any parent SPAN, but you can use the [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function to select sibling SPANs if that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

you could select the parents directly

```
$('.spanLt .spanRt .jquery-roundedBtn').removeClass("name of class");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more robust solution:

```
 $('#DefaultContent_btnRunReport').closest('div').removeClass('test123').find('span').removeClass('test123');
```

Starting point is button in question. `closest('div')` will return first parent who is `div` (not only immediate/direct parent), so if you later change markup a little, js will still work.
`find('span')` will return all spans inside previously found `div`.

Also, **only** `div`,`span` which are relevant to the button will be targeted instead of all `div`,`span` with those classes.